# Python: How to run a code for different available columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assuming I have a dataframe with columns named: `BacksGas_Flow_sccm`, `Temperature` and `Pressure`

I have written a code for one of the column(`BacksGas_Flow_sccm`), and I would like to run this code for all the different columns available:

**My Code:**

```
data = pd.read_excel('gpmd.xlsx', header = 0)
df = data.loc[:, ['ContextID','BacksGas_Flow_sccm', 'StepID', 'Time_ms']]
X = df.copy()

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

n_estimators = 50

def iso_forest(step_id, X=X):
    s = X.loc[X['StepID'] == step_id]
    s_array = s.iloc[:,1].values.astype(float).reshape(-1,1)
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    scaled_array_s = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(s_array)
    s.iloc[:,1] = scaled_array_s
    iso_forest = IsolationForest(behaviour='new', n_estimators = n_estimators, max_samples = 'auto')
    s['iso_forest'] = iso_forest.fit_predict(s.values[:,[1]])
    return s

step25 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ContextID','BacksGas_Flow_sccm','StepID','Time_ms'])
step26 = step25.copy()
step27 = step25.copy()

for _, group in df.groupby('ContextID'):
    step25 = step25.append(group[group.index.get_loc(group[group.StepID.eq(24)].index[0]):][group.StepID.eq(1)])
    step26 = step26.append(group[group.index.get_loc(group[group.StepID.eq(24)].index[0]):][group.StepID.eq(2)])
    step27 = step27.append(group[group.index.get_loc(group[group.StepID.eq(24)].index[0]):][group.StepID.eq(3)])

united_data = pd.concat([X, step25, step26, step27])
united_data_grouped = united_data.groupby(list(united_data.columns))
uniq_data_idx = [x[0] for x in united_data_grouped.indices.values() if len(x) == 1]
X = united_data.iloc[uniq_data_idx]

step25['StepID'] = 25
step26['StepID'] = 26
step27['StepID'] = 27

step1 = iso_forest(step_id = 1, X=X)
step2 = iso_forest(step_id = 2, X=X)
step5 = iso_forest(step_id = 5, X=X)
step7 = iso_forest(step_id = 7, X=X)
step12 = iso_forest(step_id = 12, X=X)
step15 = iso_forest(step_id = 15, X=X)
step16 = iso_forest(step_id = 16, X=X)
step19 = iso_forest(step_id = 19, X=X)
step24 = iso_forest(step_id = 24, X=X)
step25 = iso_forest(step_id = 25, X=step25)
step26 = iso_forest(step_id = 26, X=step26)
step27 = iso_forest(step_id = 27, X=step27)

length = 27
xmarks = range(1,length+1,1)

plt.figure(2)
plt.scatter(step1.values[step1['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step1.values[step1['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green', label = 'Normal')
plt.scatter(step1.values[step1['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step1.values[step1['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red', label = 'Outlier')
plt.scatter(step2.values[step2['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step2.values[step2['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step2.values[step2['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step2.values[step2['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.scatter(step5.values[step5['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step5.values[step5['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step5.values[step5['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step5.values[step5['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.scatter(step7.values[step7['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step7.values[step7['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step7.values[step7['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step7.values[step7['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.scatter(step12.values[step12['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step12.values[step12['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step12.values[step12['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step12.values[step12['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.scatter(step15.values[step15['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step15.values[step15['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step15.values[step15['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step15.values[step15['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.scatter(step16.values[step16['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step16.values[step16['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step16.values[step16['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step16.values[step16['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.scatter(step19.values[step19['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step19.values[step19['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step19.values[step19['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step19.values[step19['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.scatter(step24.values[step24['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step24.values[step24['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step24.values[step24['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step24.values[step24['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.scatter(step25.values[step25['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step25.values[step25['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step25.values[step25['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step25.values[step25['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.scatter(step26.values[step26['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step26.values[step26['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step26.values[step26['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step26.values[step26['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.scatter(step27.values[step27['iso_forest'] == 1, 2], step27.values[step27['iso_forest'] == 1, 1], c = 'green')
plt.scatter(step27.values[step27['iso_forest'] == -1, 2], step27.values[step27['iso_forest'] == -1, 1], c = 'red')
plt.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
plt.xlabel('StepIDs')
plt.ylabel('Normalized Parameter values')
plt.title('With Isolated Forest')
plt.xticks(xmarks)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

def negative_positive_one(df):
    p = df[df['iso_forest'] == 1]
    n = df[df['iso_forest'] == -1]
    print('p_min:', min(p['BacksGas_Flow_sccm']), ',', 'p_max:', max(p['BacksGas_Flow_sccm']))
    print('n_min:', min(n['BacksGas_Flow_sccm']), ',', 'n_max:', max(n['BacksGas_Flow_sccm']))
    bottom_red = min(p['BacksGas_Flow_sccm']) - min(n['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'])
    top_red = max(n['BacksGas_Flow_sccm']) - max(p['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'])
    print('bottom red:', bottom_red)
    print('top red:', top_red)
    middle_green = max(p['BacksGas_Flow_sccm']) - min(p['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'])
    print('middle green:', middle_green)
    red_green_ratio = (bottom_red+top_red)/middle_green
    print('The red to green ratio:', red_green_ratio)
    return red_green_ratio

red_green_ratio = {
'step1_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step1),
'step2_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step2),
'step5_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step5),
'step7_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step7),
'step12_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step12),
'step15_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step15),
'step16_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step16),
'step19_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step19),
'step24_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step24),
'step25_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step25),
'step26_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step26),
'step27_rgr' : negative_positive_one(step27)
}
```

I would like to know if there is an easy or efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try something like:

```
def negative_positive_one(df, col):
    p = df[df['iso_forest'] == 1]
    n = df[df['iso_forest'] == -1]
    print('p_min:', min(p[col]), ',', 'p_max:', max(p[col]))
    print('n_min:', min(n[col]), ',', 'n_max:', max(n[col]))
    bottom_red = min(p[col]) - min(n[col])
    top_red = max(n[col]) - max(p[col])
    print('bottom red:', bottom_red)
    print('top red:', top_red)
    middle_green = max(p[col]) - min(p[col])
    print('middle green:', middle_green)
    red_green_ratio = (bottom_red+top_red)/middle_green
    print('The red to green ratio:', red_green_ratio)
    return red_green_ratio

red_green_ratios = {}

for col in df.columns:
    red_green_ratios[col] = negative_positive_one(df, col)
```

This way, you will have a dict and for every key (which is the name of the column), you will have the result of your function.

Let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: That helps me for one part of the code, but is it possible for the entire code to be generalized?

Comment: Yes, but it really depends on what you want to do. I think you will have some refacto to do. But if you want to do so, just be aware that you can loop on columns so that you wan create re-usable functions